# How to optimize the loop that do mask between two buffers

Tags: c

I have two uint8_t buffers with same size, one for data called A, one for mask which have 3 values 128 for mask, 0 and 255 called M. The action is:

```
if (M[i] == 128) 
    A[i] = A[i];
else 
    A[i] = M[i];
```

Here is my code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 3000000

int main() {

    uint8_t A[BUFF_SIZE];
    uint8_t M[BUFF_SIZE];

    // Initialize A buffer with random values
    ...
    // Initialize M buffer with mask value
    ...

    while(1) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < BUFF_SIZE; i++) {
            M[i] == 128 ? 1 : A[i] = M[i];
        }
        usleep(33000);
    }
}
```

If I compile without `-fopenmp`, the program eats about 50% CPU, otherwise, it eats about 99% CPU. My system has 6 cores.

So why is parallel for loop in this case takes much more CPU than serialization?

Is there any way to speed up this loop (value of mask can be change but value 0 and 255 cannot)?

Comment: I would change `M[i] == 128 ? 1 : A[i] = M[i];` to `if (M[i] != 128) A[i] = M[i];` for readability. I thought about that line way too long if it is correct as it is.

Comment: Yes, you can change as you do for readability